# why is &reg; not working when used with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symbols

I am having a problem I want to attach the registered trademark symbol a button and I want it to be done with jquery because there are lots and lots of buttons that require the sign when I used it with html for example(below) it worked.

```
<input type="button" class="button_a" value="Value &reg;" />
```

But when I used jquery as below it returns as plain text:

```
$('.button_a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("value",$(this).attr("value")+" &reg;");
});
```

I don't want to waste my time and space by putting `&reg;` in all the button's values so I want it to be done in jquery but what am I doing incorrect.

I know it's a sluggish question but please someone help out me in this question

Javascript may be also used.

For more info please comment and ask

Thanks....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&reg;` is being rendered as a text string, but you can use unicode `\u00AE`

```
$('.button_a').each(function(){
    this.value = this.value +" \u00AE";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fbuohvm1/

or just `®`:

```
$('.button_a').each(function(){
    this.value = this.value +" ®";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fbuohvm1/1/

Answer (score 5):

Because, while the DOM you are manipulating was initialised from an HTML document, you are now dealing with DOM and not HTML. You are writing the value *as text* not as HTML.

You need to use either a literal character (`"®"`) or a JavaScript escape sequence (`"\u00AE"`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to `encode` it first before setting the value of textbox.

```
$('.button_a').each(function () {

    $(this).val("value " + $("<div/>").html('&reg;').text());
});
```

`$("<div/>").html('&reg;').text()` will return the encoded value.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/t2gwptys/

Comment: Nice in a bit hackish way :)

Comment: @pawel Atleast this is generic, user don't have to search for the unicode equivalent for other symbols

Answer (score 0):

you need to process content by `html()`, because html entities is manipulate by `html()` function, try this code.

```
$('.button_a').each(function(){
    $(this).val($("<p/>").html($(this).val()+" &reg;").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden `div`.

```
$('.button_a').each(function(){
    var decoded = $('<div/>').html('&reg;').text();
    $(this).val($(this).val() + ' ' + decoded);
});
```

See **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/xalvin11/gz7rb9ou/)**

Answer (score 0):

In your case plain js is more straightforward:

```
$('.button_a').each(function(){
    this.value += " &reg;";
});
```

-- EDIT --
Unfortunately this is still escaped, in fact you need

```
    this.value += " \u00AE";
```

Comment: Hmmm, didn't expect that. Need to change to the unicode sequence then.