# How can I replace a character or group of characters with a unicode character using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, unicode, replace

I have the following function:

```
function bindTrademarkReplacement() {
//48 = 0 [for close parenthesis]
$("input, textarea").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 48) {
        console.log("here") //(to make sure I'm getting in the branch
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace("(R)", "\u00AE"));
    }
});
}
```

I have tried the following:

- `$(this).val($(this).val().replace("(R)", "\u00AE"));` //Doesn't error, but doesn't work.
- `$(this).val($(this).val().replace("(R)", "®"));` //Doesn't error, but doesn't work.
- `$(this).val($(this).val().replace("(R)", "`®`"));` //Obviously doesn't work, nor should it.

I've even tried this disastrous hack (just to see what would happen):

- `$(this).val($(this).val().replace("(R)", $("</div>").html(`®`).text());` //Just a bad idea, but also doesn't work.

All of the sources I've seen seems to indicate that this should be possible by simply using the "\u00AE" value, but I've had absolutely no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

### Additional Information

- The element I'm testing on is a `<textarea>` element (not a problem for jQuery's `.val()`)
- I've tried other variations, but they are basically just the same as I've already listed (like using `&reg;` instead of `&#174;`, for instance.
- I've have tried this with generic information such as `.replace("(R)", "test")` to ensure that the replacement function is not, somehow, the problem (like an oversight on my part).

Sources I've looked at:

- [why is &reg; not working when used with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209848/why-is-reg-not-working-when-used-with-jquery)
- http://jeffancel.com/quick_non-unicode_javascriptjquery_replace_again/2011/02
- http://www.davidkelly.ie/2009/01/12/replace-the-euro-symbol-e-using-javascript-jquery/

Comment: Should work - at least with native js syntax https://jsfiddle.net/n2gzrrev/

Comment: It does (though your regex wasn't necessary, it was better, so thank you for that).  Just for the heck of it, I'll tell you what the problem was, though you wouldn't be able to tell from my question.  I have the CSS on these text fields set to uppercase (as my clients demand). So, I was only checking based on 'seeing' the capitol 'R', but of course under the scene it was registering the lowercase 'r' as that was what I was typing.  Facepalm moment ensues...